# MVC5 Ajax PartialView

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, unobtrusive-validation

I need to refresh a div with a PartialView by using Ajax.BeginForm.
I have done this over a dozen times in MVC4 and it worked flawlessly. In MVC5, it doesn't work though :(

Here are the steps I took:

- Create a new project “PartialAjax” in Visual Studio 2013 (ASP.NET Web Application / MVC)
- Right click Views/Home and Add View > Check “Create as partial view” > name it “_Test”
- Code for this _Test.cshtml view:

  ```
  <p>From now on I'm gonna change my life: @DateTime.Now.ToString()</p>
  ```
- Edit the Views/Home/Index.cshtml view:

  ```
  @{
              ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
  }
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeLife", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "test", HttpMethod = "Post" }, null))
  {
      <input type="submit" value="Start" />
  }

  <div id="test">
      @Html.Partial("_Test")
  </div>
  ```
- Put this in your HomeController:

  ```
  public ActionResult ChangeLife()
        {
            return this.PartialView("_Test");
        }
  ```

If I click Manage NuGet packages, jQuery and Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation are installed by default.

Comment: The presence of the NuGet packages doesn't mean that the scripts have been loaded; which bundles are loaded in your _Layout?

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr"), @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"),     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

Comment: Yep; the unobtrusive ajax script is included in the `"~/bundles/jqueryval"` bundle, so you need to add that to either the layout or the individual view(s).

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Might be easier to figure out if you include a more complete example of what you're doing; also, the Unobtrusive Ajax script is a separate NuGet package (though it's normally installed as well): https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to install Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax and render the javascript bundles for jqueryval (existing but not rendered) and added a new one for the unobtrusive.ajax script files.

new bundle in BundleConfig class:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

added render methods for the two bundles in _Layout.cshtml (underneath the jquery render):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
```